# Can't update value on the main form

Tags: c#, winforms

I my game on the WF I have a main form (**left**) and it's child form (**right**). In the child form I can change value of the progress bar and it works fine. But I have the same progress bar on the main form and I want to update it too. I can't do it.

[VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpfQnI83NcU&feature=youtu.be)

[image]

**Code of the child form:**

```
private MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();

// Button "Close"
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mainForm.MyInitializeComponent(); // This code must update value on the main form
    this.Close();
}
```

**Code of the main form:**

```
public void MyInitializeComponent()
{
    label33.Text = indicators.Food + "%";
    progressBar1.Value = indicators.Food;
}
```

If I'll open child form after I closed it, I see the changed value, ie it is stored. In both forms, the value is taken from a single variable.

**Indicators.cs:**

```
public sealed class Indicators
    {
        public Indicators()
        {
            Indicators.food = 75;
        }

        private static int food;

        public int Food
        {
            get { return food; }
            set { food = value; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `indicators` and where do you set its `Food` property? Code you've shown is not sufficient.

Comment: I think you need a global instance of the class. And refer to it from all forms. Also make a property change events.

Comment: Use the debugger, set breakpoints, compare your varuiables actual values against expected values.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Sorry, forgot about that. Posted code of Indicators class

Comment: @dima Code of `Indicators` class is not so much needed here. You're using some `indicators` variable in `MyInitializeComponent`. My question was about origin of this variable and where it's property being set. Does this variable somehow belongs to child form? You're expecting `Food` propery to be filled - do you actually fill it somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the main form add a form closed handler to the child form to update it's UI when the child is closed:

```
var childForm = new ChildForm();
childForm.FormClosed += (s, args) => MyInitializeComponent();
//...
childForm.Show();
```